# i want to use ternary operator in react-native how can i fix my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

hi i want to use ternary operator

if cookup has value i want to render

```
   <FlatList
            data={cookUp}
            keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
            // keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
            //     return `${index}`;
            // }}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
            <Hey>
                {item.name}
            </Hey>
            )}
        />
```

but if cookup has a [] like this

[image]

i want to render

```
           <Hey>hiaaaaaa</Hey>
```

here is my code

```
  return (
    cookUp ?  ( 
        <FlatList
            data={cookUp}
            keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
            // keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
            //     return `${index}`;
            // }}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
            <Hey>
                {item.name}
            </Hey>
            )}
        />
    ) :
        (<Hey>hiaaaaaa</Hey>)
   );
```

how can i do this?? how can i fix my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ListEmptyComponent prop in the flatlist

```
<FlatList
            data={cookUp}
            keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
            // keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
            //     return `${index}`;
            // }}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
            <Hey>
                {item.name}
            </Hey>
            )}
            ListEmptyComponent={<Hey>hiaaaaaa</Hey>}
        />
```

This will render the 'hiaaaaaa' when the data is empty. No need to go through the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    return (
    { cookUp.length > 0 ?  ( 
        <FlatList
            data={cookUp}
            keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
            // keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
            //     return `${index}`;
            // }}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
            <Hey>
                {item.name}
            </Hey>
            )}
        />
    ) :
        (<Hey>hiaaaaaa</Hey>)
    }
  )
```

Don't forget to youse {} when you're writing JS in JSX. Other is just JavaScript that you should probably dive into a bit deeper before frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty straightforward:

```
  return (
    <Fragment>
     {cookUp.length ?  ( 
        <FlatList
            data={cookUp}
            keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
            // keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
            //     return `${index}`;
            // }}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
            <Hey>
                {item.name}
            </Hey>
            )}
        />
    ) :
        (<Hey>hiaaaaaa</Hey>)
   }
   </Fragment>
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach,

`cookUp` is an empty array, so you have to check the length for verifying the data is empty.

```
return (
<>
    {cookUp?.length ?  ( 
        <FlatList
            data={cookUp}
            keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
            // keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
            //     return `${index}`;
            // }}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
            <Hey>
                {item.name}
            </Hey>
            )}
        />
    ) :
        (<Hey>hiaaaaaa</Hey>) }
   </>
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

An empty `Array` is true.

After checking `cookUp` is `true` you can use the `isArray` method on `cookUp`:

```js
return (
    cookUp
      ? Array.isArray(cookUp)
        ? (
          <FlatList
            data={cookUp}
            keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
            // keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
            //     return `${index}`;
            // }}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
            <Hey>
                {item.name}
            </Hey>
            )}
        />
      ) 
      : ( < Hey > hiaaaaaa < /Hey>));
    : null
```